# Deadlock during creating view

Tags: postgresql, view, locking, deadlock

I've got Postgres 11

Our database developers made a procedure, which does the following steps:

1. We have table with data and our users are getting data from view on that table.
2. During procedure we get fresh data in temp table
3. Procedure calls another procedure which: creates new table like the main with data,

inserts fresh data into that table, lock old table with data which can be used with users,

rename to something else, new table is renamed into old table.

4. After that we recreate views on this table.

```
--Create views
    for _create_view_rec in select schemaname, viewname, definition from temp_views
        loop
                        begin
                                execute ( 
                    'create or replace view ' || _create_view_rec.schemaname ||
                    '.' || _create_view_rec.viewname || ' as ' || _create_view_rec.definition
                );
            end;
        end loop;
```

5. We sometimes get error: [40P01] deadlock detected SQL statement "create or replace view
   PL/pgSQL function replace_tables(text,text) line 104 at ....
   Can someone help? I don't find any case when deadlock happens when creating view

Can you help with advices?

Comment: The deadlock is most likely being caused by concurrent sessions each trying to recreate the view and rename the table. I'm curious as to the use case for such a convoluted process. My advice: take a critial look at the design and determine if there is a simpler way to achieve the end result. You might explore deleting the data in the table the view depends on and inserting the new data all within a single transaction. The users would continue to see the old data until the transaction completes.

Comment: This procedure is called every three hours by cron and average time of execution is 2,5 hour. You mean that procedure cannot manage to finish the process and then another is called and trying to do the same? The process is rather tricky, we used materialized view with concurrent refreshing, but we were tired of bloating. And this approach with substitution helps avoid this. But we started to get these errors from time to time - it is launched 8 times a day and fails about once or twice

Comment: Your original description sounds like a complicated approach to inserting new data into a table. I must have missed some detail about the data flow/processing that warrants not directly inserting the new data into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem.
When I lock the table on which view is made, it takes some time to rename (the process how it goes is somelike mentioned here https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position).
And if someone from another session is trying to get data from view, then the error goes -

```
SQL Error [40P01]: ERROR: deadlock detected
  Process 2720940 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 1200102404 of database 16390; blocked by process 2720942.
Process 2720942 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 1200108934 of database 16390; blocked by process 2720940.
  See server log for query details.
  SQL statement "create or replace land.vw_test as  SELECT testing.id
   FROM land.testing;"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 115 at EXECUTE
```

It means that even if I get the lock on main table, I cant replace view, because it needs to be replaced on table with another OID.
So I managed to solve problem - I need to Lock the view, not the main table. Or better lock view on the first step and for insurance the table.
In this case, even if someone will try to get data from view, it won't cause deadlock during substitution of tables